# Isometry between cone and cylinder

Tags: differential-geometry, isometry

In a certain exercise I have been asked to find an isometry between a portion of the cylinder $S = \{ x^2+y^2 = 2: 0 < z < 1\}$ and the complete cone $S_* = \{x^2+y^2 = 2z^2:  0 < z < 1 \}$. I need to find an explicit formula. However, I have really no idea of how to start. I would really appreciate if somebody could give me a hand. I might be able to find an isometry between that cone and the cylinder and the plane $z = 0$ for example, but not between those geometric figures I said above.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by an isometry?

Comment: Talk to the person who asked you to find such an isometry what do they mean by it and what do they mean by "a portion." Almost surely they mean a Riemannian isometry (of metrics induced from the standard flat metric on the Euclidean space) and a "portion" means "a nonempty open subset." The problem is meant to illustrate that zero curvature surfaces are locally isometric.

Comment: I haven't been taught about Riemann, only about first fundamental forms. A "portion" of a regular surface is a regular surface which is contained in the original surface. The definition of isometry is above.

Answer (score 1):

What do you think to the map

$$ F\colon \text{cone}\to \text{cylinder}, \qquad (x,y,z)\mapsto (x/z, y/z, z) $$

Comment: Is this an isometry? (That is, it preserves distances and angles).

Comment: So for an Isometry you mean a map such that ||F(v)||=||v|| for each $v\in Cone$?

Comment: Yes, which I think is the same as $\langle F(v), F(w) \rangle = \langle v,w \rangle$

Comment: Yeah okay, but where are living your vectors? Just on the cone?

Comment: Exactly, they are inside the cone.